# Java fastest parser for OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing

What is the fastest way to parse date/times into OffsetDateTimes in Java? Is there a library which is faster than the standard library?

e.g.

```
OffsetDatetime x = Something.parse("2018-01-02T12:34:56+00:00");
```

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: You mean string to object? Check Jasckson.

Comment: I mean String -> OffsetDateTime (I have updated the question with an example). The standard library is fine but I would like to know if there's a library that's known to be much, much faster

Comment: What's wrong with [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)? Do you have any metrics that prove that the standard parsing library is slow? And like @shmosel asked, what are the requirements?  How is it too slow?

Comment: I'm just curious as to whether there's a faster library and if there's a benchmark that shows which if any is the fastest

Comment: Hi John welcome to Stack Overflow.  Try and provide more clarity in your question by editing it and not just adding comments.  Give some background/context for your question.  As it stands your question is a bit vague and short.

Comment: What's the use of a faster library if there might be an even faster one?

Comment: Do you absolutely need `OffsetDateTime`? Or is an instant-like type good enough? If so then you might experiment with my lib Time4J and its class `ChronoFormatter`. Unfortunately I have not yet found the time to do any jmh-based benchmark but the performance should probably  be better. Most important however, use constants for the formatter because such formatters are expensive in construction.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Surely your formatter can parse into something that can be converted to `OffsetDateTime`? Of course the conversion takes time too, yet you may still be able to outperform the built-in parser? Even though you have no measurement, it might be worth an answer? While the question is only asked out of curiosity, it may end up being the most direct and interesting answer…

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge the answer is no, there is no other library for parsing strings like `2018-01-02T12:34:56+00:00"` (ISO 8601 format) into `OffsetDateTime` objects. I would have expected to have heard or read about it, had one existed.

I am on thin ice with the next point, but I am also under the impression that the standard library (AKA java.time) is efficient enough and likely about as fast as you can expect to get.

**Edit:** I got curious and wrote my own parse method to see if I would be able to outperform the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse`. I was. My own method (source below) hasn’t got the flexibility of the built-in method, it accepts only a single out of the vast number of variants of the standard format, which may be its strong point performance-wise. Parsing your string a million times took:

- 1.034 seconds using `OffsetDateTime.parse`
- 0.117 seconds using my own method

This is not a recommendation! I would probably never use my own method. For the vast majority of purposes the maintenance burden won’t be worth it. If one day a different variant of ISO 8601 turns up, you will have an expensive support issue and bug fix.

My method is pretty simple:

```
private static final OffsetDateTime parse(String s) {
    char offsetSign;
    if (s.length() != 25
            || s.charAt(4) != '-'
            || s.charAt(7) != '-'
            || s.charAt(10) != 'T'
            || s.charAt(13) != ':'
            || s.charAt(16) != ':'
            || ((offsetSign = s.charAt(19)) != '+' && offsetSign != '-')
            || s.charAt(22) != ':') {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int offsetHours = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(20, 22));
    int offsetMinutes = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(23, 25));
    if (offsetSign == '-') {
        offsetHours = -offsetHours;
        offsetMinutes = -offsetMinutes;
    }
    return OffsetDateTime.of(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4)),
            Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5, 7)),
            Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 10)), 
            Integer.parseInt(s.substring(11, 13)), 
            Integer.parseInt(s.substring(14, 16)), 
            Integer.parseInt(s.substring(17, 19)), 
            0,
            ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(offsetHours, offsetMinutes));
}
```

I am aware of bugs in the code. I don’t think it’s worth to test thoroughly and fix bugs for this answer since it’s not likely to affect performance much.

Comment: Well, a full-featured formatter/parser is naturally much slower than such simple workarounds which can leave out any bloated machinery. However, your method can still be optimized, see the usage of `Integer.parseInt(...)`. By the way, I have also invested a lot of time and energy into the optimization of my class `net.time4j.format.expert.ChronoFormatter` whose performance is probably somewhere in the middle between `java.time` and your manual approach.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

At less than a millisecond per parse, you need not worry about optimizing parsing by `OffsetDateTime`. Surely you must have bigger fish to fry.

## Details

Let's try a little benchmark test.

**Caveat:** Micro-benchmarks are notoriously unreliable. But hopefully this gets us close to a realistic understanding.

**Caveat:** I rushed this code and this posting. Please double-check my work.

In my feeble attempt to avoid runtime optimization by the JVM, I use 31 distinct values, one for each day of the month of January. I repeat these a thousand times for a list of 31,000. Then I shuffled the list.

Nevertheless my results suggest there is a heavy dose of optimization at runtime. The nanoseconds per parse varies *widely by the number of loops.

- 100_000 loops = 1,573 nanoseconds each parse (1 microsecond)
- 10_000 = 4,243
- 1_000 = 10,177
- 100 = 31,125
- 1 = 693,687 nanos each parse. (693 microseconds, over half a millisecond).

I used Java 11 JVM *Zulu* product by Azul Systems, an implementation based on OpenJDK, version 11.0.2. Ran on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Summary of results:

- The worst case for a few is less than a [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) for each parse.
- The best case is only one [*micro*second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) each.

My conclusion:

- Do not worry about parsing your `OffsetDateTime` input strings.
- You may be falling into the trap of [*premature optimization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Code.

```
System.out.println( "INFO - Starting the OffsetDateTime parsing benchmark." );

List < String > inputsShort = new ArrayList <>( 31 );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-01T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-02T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-03T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-04T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-05T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-06T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-07T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-08T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-09T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-10T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-11T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-12T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-13T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-14T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-15T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-16T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-17T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-18T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-19T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-20T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-21T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-22T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-23T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-24T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-25T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-26T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-27T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-28T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-29T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-30T12:34:56+00:00" );
inputsShort.add( "2018-01-31T12:34:56+00:00" );

int loops = 100; // 100_000=1,573 nanos each parse. 10_000=4,243. 1_000=10,177. 100=31,125. 1=693,687 nanos each parse.
List < String > inputs = new ArrayList <>( inputsShort.size() * loops );
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= loops ; i++ ) {
    inputs.addAll( inputsShort );
}
Collections.shuffle( inputs );
//System.out.println( inputs );

long start = System.nanoTime();
for ( String input : inputs ) {
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
}
long stop = System.nanoTime();
long nanosPerParse = ( ( stop - start ) / inputs.size() );
System.out.println( "INFO: nanosPerParse: " + nanosPerParse + " for a count of: " + inputs.size() + "." );
```